# Cannot uninstall NetBeans 7.3 on Windows 8

Tags: windows, uninstall, netbeans

I have NetBeans 7.3 installed on my laptop, and it is really bugging me because I cannot uninstall it!

If I try to remove it from Windows 8 add/remove programs, I get the error;

```
The specified target component - nb-base/7.3.0.0.201302132200 
was not found in the registry. The installer can continue as 
if the target component was specified.
Click yes to continue, No to exit the installer.
```

Clicking no obviously exits and nothing is removed. Clicking yes the installer completes the uninstall very quickly and still nothing is removed, the program is fully functional after.

I have also tried `Revo Uninstaller` but NetBeans 7.3 doesn't even show up in there.

Can someone tell me how to remove this program from my computer, either manually or to fix the error so that it can uninstall.

Comment: So just delete the program's directory.  It sounds like the registry keys were already removed.

Comment: And/or perhaps try reinstalling it and then uninstall it again.

Comment: @Ramhound You were right, this is also why it wasn't showing in revo. I removed the folders, then re-installed, and uninstalled successfully, I have no idea how the registry keys were removed though!

Comment: @CarlG - The original installation likely simply failed without your knowlege, you uninstalled it and because their installer sucks, it didn't remove itself.  Any number of logical explainations can be thought of.

Comment: Should I delete this question, as it has no answers even though it is solved?

Comment: I just ran into this same problem with Netbeans 7.3.1 on Windows 8 and by deleting the Netbeans directory I was able to re-install and then uninstall the program successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlG Answer it yourself and set the answered flag ;)

Answer (score 6):

From: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/65/install.html#troubleshooting

About the Installer Working Directory

The installer stores data about installation sessions in the installer working directory. Examples of this data are the list of components installed on your system, installation log messages, and registry data.

The default location for the installer working directory is %USERPROFILE%.nbi on Windows and ~/.nbi on other platforms. The log subdirectory contains the installation log files.

Cleaning Up After Incomplete Installations

After incomplete or unsuccessful installations, you might need to clean up your system from previous installations.

For Microsoft Windows, Solaris OS, and Linux:

```
Delete the installer working directory.
Delete the installation directories of the IDE and the GlassFish application server.
On the Windows platform, delete all nbi* registry entries from the following registry keys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

For Mac OS X:

```
Drag the program folders or files to the Trash.
```

Answer (score 2):

The uninstallation may fail if uninstaller.exe do not find the .nbi folder at the home directory.

Home directory:

- Windows : C:\Users\.nbi
- Unix: ~.nbi

When this happens?

1. Unsuccessful installations / uninstallations
2. Installed the netbeans from one user and uninstalling from the different user.

Solution:

1. Problem 1: Follow the answer from "Dual"
2. Problem 2:

   1. Open the home directory of the user who installed it.
   2. Copy ".nbi" folder and ".netbeans-XXXX" to your home directory.
   3. Run the uninstaller once again.

The program should uninstall successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in my Windows 7 VM and solved it by running the uninstaller.exe as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem as above.

Prior to the "symptoms", I installed the application in a newly created folder on the C drive (Not the Program Files default installation directory).

I then changed the name of the folder directory where the executable was installed to enable a third-party script to launch the NetBeans executable as the script required no spaces in the path. In any case, in attempting to uninstall the application again, I got the above error.

I tried running the command as outlined [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407291/unable-to-uninstall-netbeans-8-0-2):

C:\Netbeans\NetBeans 8.0.2>uninstall.exe --userdir C:\Users\mark.burl.nbi

it launched the uninstall but the same error popped up.

I then undertook the following and the problem was solved for me:

1. I **manually** deleted the **NetBeans executable folder**.
2. I then **reinstalled** NetBeans to the **default Program Files location**.
3. I then **uninstalled** **NetBeans** **again** no problem.